# TypeError: str object is not callable hnmnj

Tags: python

Why isn't this code working? It is giving the typeError in the following line in main file:

`print(question.question_prompt())`

Question.py:

```
class Question:
    def __init__(self, question_prompt, answer):
        self.question_prompt = question_prompt
        self.answer = answer
```

main file:

```
from Question import Question

question_prompts = [
    "How many minutes are there in an hour?\n(a) 40\n(b) 50\n(c) 60\n(d) 70",
    "How man seconds are there in a minute?\n(a) 40\n(b) 50\n(c) 60\n(d) 70",
    "How man milliseconds are there in a second?\n(a) 80\n(b) 60\n(c) 120\n(d) 100"
]

questions = [
    Question(question_prompts[0], "c"),
    Question(question_prompts[1], "c"),
    Question(question_prompts[2], "d")
]

        
# actual game
score = 0

for question in questions:
    print(question.question_prompt())
    answer = input("Answer: ")
    if answer == question.answer:
        score += 1

print(f"You answer {score}/3 questions correctly. ")
print("Thanks for playing! ")
```

Comment: Just like the error says, `question.question_prompt` is a string.  What are you expecting `question.question_prompt()` to do and why?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
print(question.question_prompt())
```

with

```
print(question.question_prompt)
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the brackets from:

```
print(question.question_prompt())
```

So it will be:

```
print(question.question_prompt)
```

Note: There are 1000 Milliseconds in a second.